# How are the following types of neural network-like techniques called?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, black-box

The neural network applications I've seen always learn the weights of their inputs and use fixed "hidden layers".

But I'm wondering about the following techniques:

1) fixed inputs, but the hidden layers are no longer fixed, in the sense that the functions of the input they compute can be tweaked (learned)

2) fixed inputs, but the hidden layers are no longer fixed, in the sense that although they have clusters which compute fixed functions (multiplication, addition, etc... just like ALUs in a CPU or GPU) of their inputs, the weights of the connections between them and between them and the input can be learned (this should in some ways be equivalent to 1)  )

These could be used to model systems for which we know the inputs and the output but not how the input is turned into the output (figuring out what is inside a "black box"). Do such techniques exist and if so, what are they called?

Comment: For clarification: In 1) do you mean the transfer function as the trainable function? For 2) I can't see something special (except the parts you take from 1) ). Your described goal of learning a function that maps input -> output for known inputs is something a "normal" neural network is already capable of (e.g. XOR). There are multiple techniques to "figure out the inside of the black box" as well. The network you describe wouldn't explain more than the existing models. So I'm not seeing the benefit for this purpose yet.

Comment: Yes, in 1) I meant the transfer function (each neuron or cluster of neurons could develop their own transfer function as training goes on). To be precise by "known" inputs I meant knowing exactly what goes in (inputs AND their relative strengths) but having almost no model of how the input is turned into the output (you don know if the inputs are added or multiplied by each other, etc...) Are you saying these two techniques are not used (they seemed to me like obvious things to try out with neural networks, but if nobody uses them they were probably found inferior to other techniques)?

Comment: P.S. I know that a normal neural network can in principle model any function, no matter how wiggly, but iirc you have to have an idea how many neurons and layers you are going to need. It seems to me that neural networks with variable transfer functions might be more flexible in this regard (although you of course still need some, problem specific, minimum number of neurons). Intuitively I think that it would also provide more clues about the underlying math of the problem you're studying (you might instantly discover that your black box uses a very simple function), but I could be very wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For part (1) of your question, there are a couple of relatively recent techniques that come to mind.

The first one is a type of feedforward layer called "maxout" which computes a piecewise linear output function of its inputs.

Consider a traditional neural network unit with `d` inputs and a linear transfer function. We can describe the output of this unit as a function of its input `z` (a vector with `d` elements) as `g(z) = w z`, where `w` is a vector with `d` weight values.

In a maxout unit, the output of the unit is described as

```
g(z) = max_k w_k z
```

where `w_k` is a vector with `d` weight values, and there are `k` such weight vectors `[w_1 ... w_k]` *per unit*. Each of the weight vectors in the maxout unit computes some linear function of the input, and the `max` combines all of these linear functions into a single, convex, piecewise linear function. The individual weight vectors can be learned by the network, so that in effect each linear transform learns to model a specific part of the input (`z`) space.

You can read more about maxout networks at http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4389.

The second technique that has recently been developed is the "parametric relu" unit. In this type of unit, all neurons in a network layer compute an output `g(z) = max(0, w z) + a min(w z, 0)`, as compared to the more traditional rectified linear unit, which computes `g(z) = max(0, w z)`. The parameter `a` is shared across all neurons in a layer in the network and is learned along with the weight vector `w`.

The prelu technique is described by http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852.

Maxout units have been shown to work well for a number of image classification tasks, particularly when combined with dropout to prevent overtraining. It's unclear whether the parametric relu units are extremely useful in modeling images, but the prelu paper gets really great results on what has for a while been considered the benchmark task in image classification.

Comment: From what I understand from this at first glance the techniques you are describing do indeed effectively vary the transfer functions, as in my 1). I thought about literally cycling through predefined transfer functions but the maxout technique seems much more flexible and robust and I think I have my answer (but correct me if I'm wrong): the idea of varying transfer functions is indeed used (just as I suspected), but of course in a much more clever way, examples are the variations of maxout techniques you mentioned.

Comment: @Bubba Yes, I'd say that's accurate -- people have indeed looked at learning the transfer function; these are just a couple of recent examples.